# Capturing Record Id in Lightning-datatable with a click

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lds

I have a lightning-datatable where there are many columns and one of the column is Record Name. Is there a way i get the Id of this record with a click or a click of a button on a row?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation

Refer the doc and here's the sample code check the **getSelectedName()** function

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            key-field="id"
            onrowselection={getSelectedName}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>


import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

const columns = [
     {label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'opportunityName', type: 'text'},
     {label: 'Confidence', fieldName: 'confidence', type: 'percent', cellAttributes:
     { iconName: { fieldName: 'trendIcon' }, iconPosition: 'right' }},
     {label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency', typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'EUR'}},
     {label: 'Contact Email', fieldName: 'contact', type: 'email'},
     {label: 'Contact Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone'},
];

const data = [{
                    id: 'a',
                    opportunityName: 'Cloudhub',
                    confidence: 0.2,
                    amount: 25000,
                    contact: 'jrogers@cloudhub.com',
                    phone: '2352235235',
                    trendIcon: 'utility:down'
                },
                {
                    id: 'b',
                    opportunityName: 'Quip',
                    confidence: 0.78,
                    amount: 740000,
                    contact: 'quipy@quip.com',
                    phone: '2352235235',
                    trendIcon: 'utility:up'
                }];

export default class DatatableExample extends LightningElement {
    data = data;
    columns = columns;

    // Function to fetch the selected rows details 
    getSelectedName(event) {
        const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
        // Display that fieldName of the selected rows
        for (let i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
            alert("You selected: " + selectedRows[i].opportunityName);
        }
    }
}
```